# Convert v2 to v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

**This the code of indicator , which I am looking to convert to V4 or V5, i am facing to problem to convert it to desired version. Can someone help me please?**

```
//@version=2
study(title="STUDY",overlay = true, shorttitle="STUDY")
src = close, len = input(25, minval=1, title="Length")
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

//input
myPeriod = input(defval=7, type=integer, title="Period")
myThresholdUp = input(defval=50, type=float, title="Upper Threshold")
myThresholdDn = input(defval=50, type=float, title="Lower Threshold")
myAlgoFlipToggle = input(defval=false, type=bool, title="Imverse Algorthim")
myLineToggle = input(defval=true, type=bool, title="Show Lines")
myLabelToggle = input(defval=true, type=bool, title="Show Labels")
myRSI=rsi(close, myPeriod)
```

buy = myAlgoFlipToggle ? falling(myRSI,1) and cross(myRSI, myThresholdDn) : rising(myRSI, 1)
and cross(myRSI,myThresholdUp)
sell = myAlgoFlipToggle ? rising(myRSI, 1) and cross(myRSI,myThresholdUp) : falling(myRSI,1)
and cross(myRSI, myThresholdDn)
myPosition = buy==1 ? 0 : sell==1 or myPosition[1]==1 ? 1 : 0
trendColor = buy ? red : sell ? green : na

Answer (score 1):

First convert from @version=2 to @version=3:
you only change the v-num then compile the script
and pinescript compiler will tell you what's to change.

Then you choose "convert to version 5" in the save list.
From v3 to v5 it's automated.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the ta prefix before all timeseries related functions like rma, cross, falling, rising, change. You will have to put math prefix before math function like max and min. You will have to use color prefix before colors like red and green. You will have to use suffix after input like int , float, etc

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="STUDY",overlay = true, shorttitle="STUDY")
src = close
len = input.int(25, minval=1, title="Length")
up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), len)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

//input
myPeriod = input.int(7, title="Period")
myThresholdUp = input.float(defval=50.0, title="Upper Threshold")
myThresholdDn = input.float(defval=50.0, title="Lower Threshold")
myAlgoFlipToggle = input.bool(defval=false, title="Imverse Algorthim")
myLineToggle = input.bool(defval=true, title="Show Lines")
myLabelToggle = input.bool(defval=true,  title="Show Labels")
myRSI=ta.rsi(close, myPeriod)

buy = myAlgoFlipToggle ? ta.falling(myRSI,1) and ta.cross(myRSI, myThresholdDn) : ta.rising(myRSI, 1) and ta.cross(myRSI,myThresholdUp) 
sell = myAlgoFlipToggle ? ta.rising(myRSI, 1) and ta.cross(myRSI,myThresholdUp) : ta.falling(myRSI,1) and ta.cross(myRSI, myThresholdDn) 
var myPosition=0
myPosition := buy==1 ? 0 : sell==1 or myPosition[1]==1 ? 1 : 0 
trendColor = buy ? color.red : sell ? color.green : na
plot(myPosition)
```